# Java Hibernate trouble

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this mapping:

Entity 1 Entity 2 Entity 3

And Entity 4

Entities number 1,2 and 3 have a List of Entity 4.
Entity 4 has only 2 Field's: a String(DATA) and an Id which i set to @Id and @GeneratedValue

In the database table that holds the Entity 4 data I don't want to have the String(DATA) Duplicated.

But Entity 1,2 and 3 can have in their List of Entity 4 duplicated data between them.

An Example (Instance are objects of the Entities specified):

```
Instance 1 (Entity 1): List: ["hi","hello","music"]
Instance 2 (Entity 2): List: ["tv","hi","sofa"]
Instance 3 (Entity 2): List: ["sofa","wii"]
Instance 4 (Entity 3): List: ["music","otherString"];
```

What db table entries for Entity 4 should be:
 ID     String
 1        hi
 2      hello
 3      music
 4        tv
 5       sofa
 6       wii
 7       otherString

What I'm getting is:
 ID     String
 1        hi
 2      hello
 3      music
 4        tv 
 5       hi 
 6       sofa
 7       sofa 
 8      wii
 9      music
 10     otherString

The data is duplicated. When I try to give the Field String using the @Id annotation then when I try to save an instance of entities 1,2 or 3 with a String in their List that already exists, it sends a Duplicated entry error for the Entity 4 and does not save the Entity 1,2 or 3.

How do I annotate this correctly?

Some of my code:

Entity 1,2 or 3 (they are all the same in this part of the code):

```
@Entity
 public class Entity1 {
      private List<Entity4> entity4List;

       @OneToMany(targetEntity=Entity4.class,cascade =CascadeType.ALL)
        public List<Entity4> getEntity4List() {
         return entity4List;
       }
    }
```

Entity 4:

```
@Entity
 public class Entity4 {

    private long id;
      private String stringn;

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
       public long getId() {
        return id;
       }
     }
```

And the Hibernate code where i save Entities 1,2 or 3:

```
public void addEntity1(ArrayList<String> list){
List<Entity4> L = new ArrayList<Entity4>();
for(String s:list)
{
    L.add(new Entity4(s));
 }
  Entity1 e=new Entity1(L);
   Session session = sf.getCurrentSession();
       session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(e);
     session.getTransaction().commit();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data field of Entity4 should be unique, then you should have a unique constraint for the corresponding column in the database.

And to make sure you don't create duplicated Entity4 instances in your code, you should

- search the database for an Entity4 instance with this data field
- if it already exists, add it to the list in Entity1 (or 2, or 3)
- if it doesn't exist, create a new one and add it to the list in Entity1 (or 2, or 3)

Note that you might still have two threads checking concurrently if an entity4 exists, and have those two threads create a new one concurrently. This will lead to an exception in one of the threads thanks to the unique constraint in the database.